# GIThub GUI that works over SSH

Tags: macos, git, user-interface, github

I'm trying to set up non-tech employees on using git. They connect to a server using SFTP and and then are able to use git commands in a repo. Is there a GUI for this on Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommand giving access to a server to non-tech employee.
And Git doesn't support sftp.

So I would recommend:

- [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) (GUI for Git on Mac)
- an SSH access, managed by an authorization layer like [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/)

That way, you control precisely who can clone/push/pull for a given repository, and you don't have to give access to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I like GitX on Mac and Git Extensions on Windows, both being free.